# "message": "Call to Microsoft.Web/sites failed. Error message: SkuCode 'SKU' is invalid.",

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

Trying to provision a private point connection between an Azure Web App and Storage account in the same region. I filled out all required fields, specified resource group, web app name, vnet, and subnet. I get this deployment error message:

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Call to Microsoft.Web/sites failed. Error message: SkuCode 'SKU' is invalid.",
        "details": []
    }
}

What am I doing wrong? The 'SKU' value seems very generic. Is this a bug?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue,

[image]

Since [Using Private Endpoints for Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint) is in Preview.

> The preview is available in all public regions for **PremiumV2 Windows
>   and Linux Web Apps and Elastic Premium Functions**.

You could scale up the app service plan to **P1V2** to enable the private endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now.

Comment: Does it solve your question? Why do you unmark this answer?

Comment: I didn't implement it based on the information you provided (thanks!). A colleague asked me to leave it open as he's interested in reading more opinions/workarounds

Comment: I can reproduce this issue every time since this private endpoint for the web app is in preview currently. I don't think there is a workaround unless this feature is GA and MS updates his product.